# Which loss function I should use for grayscale to rgb problem?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I'm making a model that takes a grayscale image and returns a rgb image. Now I'm using MSE as loss function but I think that this isn't a good choice. Which loss function is better to use in this type of problem?

My model is an AutoEnconder. I'm using the following functions to build it:

```
def conv2d(layer_input, filters, f_size=3, bn=True, strides_ = 2):
    d = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=f_size, padding='same', activation='relu')(layer_input)
    d = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(2,2),strides=(2,2))(d)
    d = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(d)
    if bn:
        d = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.9)(d)
    return d

def deconv2d(layer_input, skip_input, filters, f_size=4, dropout_rate=0):
    u = UpSampling2D(size=2)(layer_input)
    u = Conv2D(filters, kernel_size=f_size, strides=1, padding='same')(u)
    u = LeakyReLU(alpha=0.2)(u)

    if dropout_rate:
        u = Dropout(dropout_rate)(u)
    u = BatchNormalization(momentum=0.8)(u)
    u = Concatenate()([u, skip_input])
    return u
```

Answer (score 0):

MSE will mainly do the job when you are facing a regression problem though there are some rare classification cases where it might fit.

If I understand the purpose of your model correctly, I believe the right loss function for you would be either binary cross-entropy or categorical cross-entropy (for multiclass classification).

Check out [this Keras documentation](https://keras.io/api/losses/) for more specific information.

UPDATE: you can see this [blog post](https://blog.keras.io/building-autoencoders-in-keras.html) which covers AutoEncoder CNN models.

Comment: Why binary or categorical cross-entropy? This isn't a classification problem. My model should colorize grayscale image to rgb image

Comment: [See this blog](https://www.jeremyjordan.me/semantic-segmentation/). All the answers